# Chai not reaching .end()

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, api-design

I am using Mocha and Chai to test my Node/Express API, and I can't figure out why the test is not reaching the .end()

Here is the test:

```
it('should authenticate successfully with user credentials', function (done) {
    agent
        .post('/login')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send({ 'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'})
        .end(function (err, res) {
            console.log(res);
            console.log('***************************Authenticated*********************************************');
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        });
    done();
});
```

And here is the route I am hitting:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { successRedirect: '/' }));
```

I figure my problem may be with the fact that there is no formal response, but rather a redirect, but I am not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Start by moving `done()` to _inside_ the `end` handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution ended up being to move the done() callback into my .end() method. Thanks @robertklep

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing async methods int mocha, you should call **call** method in callback function as below.

```
it('should authenticate successfully with user credentials', function (done) {
        agent
            .post('/login')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .send({ 'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'})
            .end(function (err, res) {
                console.log(res);
                console.log('***************************Authenticated*********************************************');
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                done();
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with chai request. I want to wait for .end callback before going to another function. but I can't use mocha because I'm using cucumber. how can I wait for chai .end callback?
in fact, I want to log (1) first but it does not work properly

```
When('I submit with method {string}:', function (string, docString) {
  chai.request(app)
  .post(endpoint)
  .send(docString)
  .end(function (err, res) {
    console.log(1)
    response = res
  })
});

Then('I recieved ok', function () {
  console.log(2)
  // expect(response.status).to.deep.equal(200)
});
```